# How to read Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text in Perl?

Tags: perl

The `file` command tells me:

`tmp.txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`

`cat`,`head` and so on can not display this file correctly.

But `vim` can display it correct. `vim` tells me:

```
[~/tmp/tmp.txt] [utf-8,dos]
"tmp.txt" [converted][dos]
```

and `:set` in vim says `fileencoding=ucs-2le`

So in Perl:

```
open FH,'<:encoding(ucs-2le)',$file;
while(<FH>){
    chomp;
    # A start
    print;  
    # Perl: Wide character in print at a.pl line 12, <FH> line 1
    # And display incorrect
    # A end

    # B start
    binmode STDOUT,":utf8";
    print;  
    # display incorrect too
    # B end

}
```

How can I read this file correct in Perl?

Comment: For what it's worth, your code works perfectly for me on a small file that I just created that uses little-endian UTF-16. (I did have to remove the BOM manually, by writing `s/^\x{FEFF}//`, to prevent the "Wide character in print" warning, since UCS-2 doesn't use the BOM.)

Comment: Are you sure your terminal is expecting UTF-8?

Comment: `locale` is `en_US.UTF-8`,`:set` in vim is `termencoding=utf-8`,SecureCRT also utf8

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem would be solved either by using either `'<:encoding(UTF-16)'` or `'<:encoding(UTF-16LE)'`.  I would try the former first; it is what you need if the file has a byte-order marker (BOM).  Probably there is a BOM, and that is what is tripping up your script.  ucs-2le is an older format, similar but not the same.

For more information:

[Perl file encoding](http://perldoc.perl.org/encoding.html)

[Perl Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html)